# operator 'new' to allocate memory to store pointers

Tags: c++

This is really stupid question to ask but I really didn't find its answer anywhere else.
I am just trying to allocate memory to store pointers. It should be most easy.
But annoyingly its not working (In VS2010 on Windows)...

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int* ints;
    int** intptrs;

    // Want to allocate space for single pointer
    ints = new int[10]; // Works

    // Want to allocate space for a integer pointer
    intptrs = new (int*); // Works 

    // Want to allocate space for 10 integer pointers
    intptrs = new (int*)[10]; // error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '['
}
```

Comment: do you want intptrs to be an array of 10 elements of pointers or a pointer to a pointer of 10 elemtens?

Comment: array of 10 elements of pointers

Comment: yes. but this is just i scribble to try something quick. anyways yor answer helped :)

Comment: @Andrew than moooeeeep's answer is the right thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error with gcc:

```
$ g++ test.cc
test.cc: In function 'int main()':
test.cc:3:23: error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id
test.cc:3:23: note: try removing the parentheses around the type-id
```

So, you just need to remove the parentheses to remove the error:

```
intptrs = new int*[10];
```

As you are working with C++, I would suggest to use `std::vector` instead of the raw array:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
  // create 10 pointers to int
  std::vector<int*> intptrs(10);
}
```

(Note that the pointed to objects will not be deleted when the vector is destroyed. You need to do this manually, when you need to. Or use smart pointers instead of raw pointers, e.g., `std::shared_ptr`.)

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
- http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: @mooeeeep you need to manage the memory _manually_ before the `vector` is destructed.

Comment: @P0W Of course, but you'd need to do that with a raw array as well.

Comment: @mooeeeep Not when you have `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @P0W Before considering smart pointers I would rather try to avoid storing pointers in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

intptrrs is a pointer to a pointer. So this should work

```
*intptrs = new int[10];
```

Comment: That's actually wrong because intptrs is not initialized!
    `intptrs = new int*[10]; // init the array of array
    *intptrs = new int[10]; // init the first array
    *intptrs[0] = 1; // assign 1 to the first element`